# Как отключить OnBackPressedCallback?

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Я вызываю `DialogFragment`, и мне нужно чтобы пользователь не мог по нажатию на `OnBackPressedCallback` выйти из этого `DialogFragment`, проще говоря отключить возможность `OnBackPressedCallback`?

Пробовал решить это следующим образом, но не сработало

```
callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed()
            {
                callback.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
```

Полный код данного `DialogFragment`

```
public class DialogLogout extends DialogFragment {
    OnBackPressedCallback callback;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed()
            {
                callback.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_logout, container, false);
        TextView exit_yes = view.findViewById(R.id.exit_yes);
        TextView exit_no = view.findViewById(R.id.exit_no);

        exit_yes.setOnClickListener(v ->
                finish());

        exit_no.setOnClickListener(v -> Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).dismiss());
        return view;
    }
    private void finish() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, например можно запретить сворачивание диалога ([доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean))):

```
DialogFragment mDialog= new MyDialogFragment();
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

так же можно в `onResume` данного диалога положить слушатель нажатия на кнопку:

```
getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,android.view.KeyEvent event) {

            if ((keyCode ==  android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
                {
                     //Hide your keyboard here!!!
                     return true; // pretend we've processed it
                }
            else 
                return false; // pass on to be processed as normal
        }
    });
```

При создании диалога можно добавить отключение сворачивания в `onCreateView`:

```
setCancelable(false);
```

вот подобные обсуждения: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307858/detect-back-button-but-dont-dismiss-dialogfragment/25251122), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480114/dialogfragment-setcancelable-property-not-working/16480564#16480564)